# How do you detect HttpRequestDecoder encountering a bad message?

Tags: netty

I have a netty 4.0.33 project that's using HttpServerCodec to parse incoming HTTP messages and write outbound responses. I'm running into an issue where if a message with invalid HTTP headers is sent down the wire, HttpObjectDecoder enters a BAD_MESSAGE state, and all subsequent messages on the channel are ignored.

The code I'm using is at https://gist.github.com/adatta02/a312a63e26923c86248a

You can do the following to test:

```
ashish@ashish:~/Downloads/netty-server$ telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /index HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 6

/indexGET /index HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User;Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 6

/indexGET /index HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)

^]

telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

You'll notice that you can send one message with invalid headers (there's a semicolon in User-Agent) which works but then subsequent messages are ignored on the channel.

Any idea how to address this? Currently, I'm checking HttpRequest.getDecoderResult().isSuccess() and closing the channel if it failed but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: I would answer to use `getDecoderResult()` but you seem to look for another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the "right thing". There is no better way.